# Postfix expressions evaluation

Tags: java, stack, postfix-notation

As a newbie to Java .. How to evaluate postfix expression of multi-digit numbers including negative ones (ie. "12 -12  +")

My snippet gives "java.lang.NullPointerException" !

I used "StringTokenizer" , however it didn't work efficiently

Anyone could appreciately help improving code ?

### Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the snippet, with an indication of where you are getting the exception, and enough code to show why you think there are no null pointer uses on that line.

Comment: [link](http://ideone.com/kifq0q)

@PatriciaShanahan

Thanks for collaboration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm is:

1. read the string from the last element to the first and put each element in a stack of Strings (each element of your stack will be a single char operator or a word convertible to a number).
2. pop 3 elements convert the first two to a number and depending on the operator calculate the result
3. push the result on the stack
4. repeat 2) and 3) till the stack is empty.

Comment: The whole problem is how to convert a string object to double !


My stack implementation :
1 public interface MyStack {
2 public Object pop();
3 public Object peek();
4 public void push(Object element);
5 public boolean isEmpty();
6 public int size();
7 }

Therefor , I couldn't retrieve it to a double or int type..

@zicow56

Comment: JAva as a Stack you don't have to implement it , have a look at the DQueue interface and  for parsing a String have a look at the Scanner class